# WiFiClient.Read() returns number 1 for each character sent

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I am trying to send data to an ESP32 using TCP. The program is written in the Arduino IDE. For sending the data I am using an app called Packet Sender. The program should print the data to Serial and also back to the WiFiClient.

Whenever I send data to the ESP32 it prints '1' for each byte sent. The message "Received data" is sent correctly.

I am using this code:

```
#include <WiFi.h>

const uint ServerPort = 23;
WiFiServer Server(ServerPort);
WiFiClient RemoteClient;

const char *SSID = "SSID";
const char *WiFiPassword = "Password";

void ConnectToWifi()
{
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(SSID, WiFiPassword);
  Serial.print("Connecting to "); Serial.println(SSID);
 
  uint8_t i = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.print('.');
    delay(500);
 
    if ((++i % 16) == 0)
    {
      Serial.println(F(" still trying to connect"));
    }
  }
 
  Serial.print(F("Connected. My IP address is: "));
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void CheckForConnections()
{
  if (Server.hasClient())
  {
    Serial.println("Client spoted"); 
    if (RemoteClient.connected())
    {
      Serial.println("Connection rejected");
      Server.available().stop();
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Connection accepted");
      RemoteClient = Server.available();
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
 
  ConnectToWifi();
  
  Server.begin();
}

void loop() {
 // RemoteClient = Server.available();
 CheckForConnections();
  if(RemoteClient)
  {
    uint8_t ch;
    bool newDataReceived = false;

    while(ch = RemoteClient.read() != -1 ){
      Serial.print(ch);
      RemoteClient.write(ch);
      newDataReceived = true;
    }
    if(newDataReceived){
      Serial.println();
      RemoteClient.print("Received data");
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: operator precedence `while((ch = RemoteClient.read()) != -1 ) {`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Now it works. I didn't know that would make a difference.

Comment: without the parenthesis it is like `while(ch = (RemoteClient.read() != -1) ) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (ch = RemoteClient.read() != -1 )
```

is interpreted by the compiler as:

```
ch = (RemoteClient.read() != -1)
```

The right part evaluates to TRUE or FALSE, i.e. 1 or 0. The 1 for TRUE is what you are seeing being printed.

You can add parentheses to make it do what you want:

```
(ch = (RemoteClient.read()) != -1)
```